# How to select a view inside a custom module form

Tags: views, hooks

I would like to have "select" with some views so I can chosse one of them and the submit the selection to display the result. something like this:

[image: Block test]

And this is close to what I want :

```
  $form['title'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t('Display amount'),
//'#required' => TRUE,
'#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array('1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8')),
'#default_value' => 5,
'#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'form_ajax_submit',
    'wrapper' => 'contenido-div',
    'method' => 'replace',
    'effect' => 'fade',
   ),
    );

 $form['content'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t('Content'),
'#options' => array(node_type_get_names()),
'#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'form_ajax_submit',
    'wrapper' => 'contenido-div',
    'method' => 'replace',
    'effect' => 'fade',
),
);

$form['views'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t('views'),
'#options' => array(),
'#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'form_ajax_submit',
    'wrapper' => 'contenido-div',
    'method' => 'replace',
    'effect' => 'fade',
 ),
);
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to display nodes in view with settings (display amount and content type)?

Comment: Yes Eugene, that is what I want !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Views is a CTools Export UI based module, the correct way to load all views is by using the CTools Export function: `ctool_export_crud_load_all()`

*Example*

```
ctools_include('export');
$views = ctools_export_crud_load_all('views_view');
$options = array();
foreach ($views as $view_id => $view) {
  $options[$view_id] = $view->human_name;
}
```